# gcc "–Werror: No such file" referring to the target or the Werror usage?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to follow along with this course (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-s096-effective-programming-in-c-and-c-january-iap-2014/getting-started/), and running into some compilation problems.

It suggests using gcc, make, and the Makefile below.

I don't know if the error message I am getting has to do with something in the C source code (seems unlikely), or with the way I have configured the gcc options.

```
$ gcc-8 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-8
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.1.0/lib/gcc/8 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-8 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-checking=release --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 8.1.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 8.1.0)

$ gmake -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ cat Makefile
CC:=gcc-8
CFLAGS:=-O0 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic –Werror
CXXFLAGS:=-O0 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Weffc++ -Werror

$ cat nothing.c
int main (void){
  return 0;
}

$ gmake nothing
gcc-8 -O0 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic –Werror    nothing.c   -o nothing
gcc-8: error: –Werror: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [<builtin>: nothing] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that in your makefile the dash *before* `Werror` isn't a standard dash, it's a unicode dash (code 8211)

```
-pedantic –Werror
```

if you look closely, the lengths differ slightly. Sometimes word processors or e-mail clients switch dashes for some cosmetic reason...

The consequence is that the options parser sees that as a file, not an option, and tries to open it to compile it.

The fix is obvious when you know that: use the proper dash in `CFLAGS` (the dash is ok in `CPPFLAGS`):

```
-pedantic -Werror
```

Comment: That fixed it... I just copy-pasted from the page. I suppose next time I should type it in manually? Did you just spot that by looking at it?

Comment: yes, and also because I _know_ it should work. someone should report it to the guys if you ask me.

Comment: Good call. I just used the OCW Feedback page to report it.